# seaborn version compatible with matplotlib 2 and above in jupyter notebook 5.0.0

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have `matplotlib 2.0.2` and `seaborn 0.8` but both don't seem to be compatible in jupyter notebook 5.0.0. Before I had an older version of `matplotlib` which used to work with `seaborn`, so does anyone know if there's a compatible `seaborn` version for `matplotlib 2` and above? It doesn't throw any errors, but it simply can't apply the settings using the `seaborn` api, e.g. the below fails to change the size of the chart and apply the specified grid lines. This  doesn't throw errors in the notebook, but the settings are not applied:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.set_context(rc={"figure.figsize": (17, 8)})
```

I'm not sure if it is the order in which I am applying the imports?

See below screenshot of my python and jupyter notebook versions

[image]

Comment: matplotlib 2.0.2 is perfectly compatible with seaborn 0.8! What problem do you encounter?

Comment: thanks, let me add more detail to the question... i encounter this problem in jupyter notebook 5.0.0

Comment: ok, i have added the detail - pls see above and let me know if you have any ideas! thx

Answer (score 1):

`sns.set_style("whitegrid")` is correctly applied. Concerning `sns.set_context`, I doubt that it can be used to change the figure size; it is meant to set the context and possible adapt things like line styles. But that should apply to just any version of seaborn.

I would guess you want to use [`sns.set`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set.html#seaborn.set).

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid",rc={"figure.figsize": (17, 8)})
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, i confirm `sns.set(style="whitegrid",rc={"figure.figsize": (17, 8)})` works, but `sns.set_context(rc={"figure.figsize": (17, 8)})` did use to work before as I was always using this in all my notebooks to change the size prior updating to the latest jupyter notebook and matplotlib

Comment: Maybe it worked by accident, but since it is not actually meant to be able to change figure size, nobody cared once it didn't work anymore. Just to be sure, in which versions of matplotlib, seaborn and jupyter did it work with exactly?